# Não estou conseguindo importar um namespace que eu criei

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, namespace

Boa Noite,

Criei um `namespace` chamado: `Enums` dentro de `Models`, quando tento importar dentro de uma classe o `Enums`, não estou conseguindo...

Estou com utilizando `Entity FrameWork` com `Asp.Net core MVC`

**Estrutura das pastas**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Enum: SalesStatus**

```
namespace SalesWebMVC.Models.Enums
{
    public enum SaleStatus : int
    {
        Pending = 0,
        Billed = 1,
        Canceled = 2
    }
}
```

**Model: SalesRecord**

```
using SalesWebMVC.Models. // Não aparece o Enums aqui
{
    public class SalesRecord
    {
        public SalesStatus MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você está tentando fazer não faz sentido nenhum... não é para esse propósito que o `using` existe... Para você ter a referência do namespace Enums em sua segunda classe, você precisa fazer a declaração correta.

```
using SalesWebMVC.Models.Enums;

namespace SalesWebMVC.Models //ou o namespace correto ao qual sua classe pertence
{
    public class SalesRecord
    {
        public SalesStatus MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SandroSousa resolveu?